# Simple but effective bracket checker for inputs like this?

Tags: java, brackets, character-arrays

```
{(1,2),(3,4)};
```

How can I check that an input like the above is a set (between '{' and '}') of two pairs (integer values between '(' and ')'. Three commas, as above, must be used. My guess is that maybe some kind of search (don't know which) on a character array for the correct symbols would be best but is there any faster way?

Bear in mind that integer values could be much huger than 1, 2, 3 etc, and negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is not performance critical, you can use a quick and dirty regex.

- `-?\d+` matches a digit sequence of any length (i.e. 1 or more digits), optionally preceded by a negative sign
- Braces `{ }` and parentheses `( )` are special characters in a regex, so they must be escaped (`\{`, etc.)
- My assumption is that no whitespace is allowed. If this is not true, you will need to modify the regex to include optional whitespace `\s*` (zero or more whitespace characters) in any place where it is allowed.

The final regex should be as follows:
`\{\(-?\d+,-?\d+\),\(-?\d+,-?\d+\)\}`

If you also need to capture any of the digit values, you can add [capturing parentheses](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: Awesome! But why would that have slow performance? It's sure as hell a compact line of code

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error when I enter this:

if(possFunction.matches(\{\(-?\d+,-?\d+\),\(-?\d+,-?\d+\)\}))

Comment: You need to specify a regex string and you also need to escape backslashes.  For example, `String regexString = "\\d+"; ...`.  Note the double backslash.

Comment: As for performance, interpreting a regex requires more processing time than simply executing imperative code that you write yourself.  Depending on the types of matching and options for your regex, it may not be as optimal as a hand-coded parser. However, the difference is negligible and not worth it unless the code is in a "performance critical" path (e.g. a method that is called in your program thousands of times per second). It is usually the case that *simple* regexes are more compact and readable than the equivalent 'hand-coded' approach.